# Mongo stopped working after upgrading

Tags: mongodb

I recently upgraded mongodb from 2.6 to 3.4.1 and now it won't connect. The log shows:

```
root@synctup-stage:~# tail -30 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
2018-05-16T12:16:49.372+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:40540 #17 (3 connections now open)
2018-05-16T12:17:22.670+0000 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:43 virt:548
2018-05-16T12:17:22.670+0000 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2018-05-16T12:17:22.670+0000 [clientcursormon]  connections:3
2018-05-16T12:21:34.334+0000 [conn17] end connection 127.0.0.1:40540 (2 connections now open)
2018-05-16T12:21:44.046+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:40542 #18 (3 connections now open)
2018-05-16T12:21:44.054+0000 [conn18] end connection 127.0.0.1:40542 (2 connections now open)
2018-05-16T12:22:22.682+0000 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:44 virt:548
2018-05-16T12:22:22.682+0000 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2018-05-16T12:22:22.682+0000 [clientcursormon]  connections:2
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: 
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [conn11] end connection 127.0.0.1:35824 (1 connection now open)
2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:35822 (1 connection now open)
2018-05-16T12:27:02.684+0000 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-05-16T12:27:02.684+0000 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.684+0000 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2018-05-16T12:27:02.686+0000 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-05-16T12:27:02.686+0000 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Any gurus out there see what might be going on?

It was working fine up until the upgrade and the upgrade seemed to go well.

I get the following errors when trying to start the mongo shell:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.15
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-16T12:28:08.006+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-05-16T12:28:08.006+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service try these steps

Comment: `2018-05-16T12:21:44.046+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:40542 #18 (3 connections now open)` says that it is possible to connect to it. What errors do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: Hi Thilo, I updated the original post with the error

Comment: `2018-05-16T12:27:02.682+0000 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends` - it was stopped externally. As a side note, upgrade from 2.6 to 3.4.1 is not a trivial one. Recommended is to upgrade to 3.0, then 3.2, then  3.4, checking for regression on each step: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/

Comment: Ashish, I tried your suggestion, as I have the db dump saved, but when I try to restart mongodb I get: Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.

Comment: did you stop the mongodb service before following the steps... and kindly reply with `@`

Comment: @cnak2 I had same problem yesterday... I have followed the following steps after     stopping the mongod. service... all the steps are very crucial especially `1) sudo apt purge mongodb-org* 2) sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service`

Comment: Ashish, It worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> Simple steps given on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service) works perfect...
>
> But one thing
> haven't mentioned over there that is before following the steps you
> have to stop the `mongod.service`.

So follow these steps before follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service)

1. sudo service mongod stop
2. sudo systemctl enable mongodb