# getting Error while installing mongodb in linux

Tags: linux, mongodb

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not   installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am getting this error even i did update the repo
: `sudo apt-get update`

also i did check if there any broken packeges with
: `sudo apt-get check`

step i took to install mongodb in linux:
1) `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5`

2) `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list`

3)`sudo apt-get update`

4)sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

but still getting the same error. how can i solve this?

Comment: did you run `apt-get purge`??

Comment: yes i did and it is not installing any new packeges

Comment: or is there any other way to install these dependencies manually?

Comment: Follow these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371473/mongo-stopped-working-after-upgrading

Comment: no it is not helping me. i think i need to download software and install it manually any help will be appreciated

Comment: no problem... and please update the answer when you get the solution...

Comment: it get solved i just did : apt install mongod thats it.thanks for your help

Comment: you can answer your own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I'm using Linux Mint 17 -> Ubuntu 14.04 and I was installing with Ubuntu 16.04 resulting in this conflict.

Check your Ubuntu/Debian version - the wiki is a useful resource - before trying these commands.

If that doesn't solve it then run

```
sudo apt purge mongod* 
sudo apt purge mongodb* 
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
```

That should remove any inconsistency and then go to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ and follow the procedure.

This resolved the issue.

Comment: In my case i was using Linux Mint [Tara] which uses Ubuntu 18 (Bionic) as its official repository. 

I had to navigate to Systems Settings -> Administration Tab -> Software Sources to confirm my distribution. 

Here after, I purged all installed instances on MongoDB using 

sudo apt purge mongod* 
sudo apt purge mongodb* 
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*

And navigated to  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ as @KNDheeraj highlighted. 

It's crucial to confirm your linux distribution when installing MongoDB

Answer (score 14):

---

> ***I guess this is the problem that you are facing.***
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2Zp.png)
>
> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
>
> mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

---

***You can try the following steps to install mongodb in Ubuntu at any version:***

> ```
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt upgrade
>
> wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
> ```

***Now you may get the error like above screenshot. Try the following steps :***

> ```
> wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1\~18.04.20_amd64.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb
> ```

***Now, mongodb is ready to be installed. Run the following installation command again:***

> `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

***To check Mongodb version, run the following command :***

> `mongod --version`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aBR2.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

100% working solution!!!

The below solution worked for me to install mongodb:

1. Download libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb:

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

2. Install it using the dpkg command:

`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Work like Makhhan Malai :) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install libssl1.1`

After adding libssl1.1, follow mongoDB installation manual
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I'm also getting the following error while installing MongoDB

```
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not 
 installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not 
 installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the solution for this kind of issue
Use the following command

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo 
tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally! Below Solutions worked for me

It is because of the missing dependencies mongodb not installing on ubuntu 22.04.
The main reason is the missing of libssl1.1 dependency. So we need to install it seperately.

1. `sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common`

2.`echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list`

3.Go to root user `sudo -i` then paste this
`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

4.`apt update`

5.`apt install libssl1.1`

6.`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

7.`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`

8.`apt update`

9.`apt install -y mongodb-org`

The latest version of mongodb will be installed
To start it

1.`systemctl enable mongod`

2.`systemctl start mongod`

In case MongoDB doesn’t start run the command below to reload.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

code copied from https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/38

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have official MongoDB packages yet, so the best option now is to have Ubuntu 20.04, where official MongoDB packages are available.

It's NOT recommended to use any workaround in Ubuntu 22.04 to install MongoDB, because it can lead to problems if you gonna use it in production. Below is the workaround that worked for me:

1.Download libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb from official repository:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

2.Install it:
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

3.Proceed with the installation of MongoDB:
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org